# Bigquery GIS for shot plots

Tags: gis, google-bigquery

I wanted to see if it was possible to plot WNBA shot charts using bigquery GIS. I saw a  lot of articles about bigquery gis for latitude/longtitude data and one post about doing it with images, but was confused and not sure if it's the right use case for BQGIS.

I have the court dimensions and the shots taken this season from the wnba's stats site. If possible I would love to see what zones different shots were taken in and be able to plot out the whole court and then also "zones" within the court so for any point I could check what "zone" it's in (i.e. low post, right wing, etc.). I have the points in half court form so would only be plotting half a court.

I've transposed the points to feet so they all fall within the boundaries of the halfcourt. The rectangle dimensions of the half court are (0, 0) [Lower left corner], (50, 0) Lower Right corner, (0, 47) [Upper left corner], (50, 47) [Upper right corner]

The arc for the three point line is a little more complicated, but i have that as well as well as the other zone dimensions.

Comment: I don't see a question here! what is the question? what kind of help you are asking for? - not clear!

Comment: Is this possible or a good use case? If so, how would I go about doing it. I’ve tried using geojson and following other tutorials and when I use distance functions I get the completely wrong answers

Comment: if you have all needed data  - YES - it is possible. provide example of data and logic you envision for visualization - so we will have chance to help

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. Will edit in the morning and provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it this way, although it might be not the best way to use BigQuery GIS.

Seems like you map court position to coordinates. This is fine for GIS systems working with planar geometries. BQ GIS would interpret them as lat/lon, *on a sphere*, and with ranges up to 50 degrees this would introduce spherical distortion. While usually BQ GIS provides more precise answer thanks to spherical geography, you'll get less precise one.

If you do go this route, I suggest using smaller ranges, e.g. scale everything down 100x and use range (0, 0) to (0.5, 0.47) to minimize these distortions, the distortions should be tiny at this scale.